# SIM800c does not power up by pulling down PWR KEY

Tags: sim800

As far as I understand if I put power and gnd connections to SIM800c (chip), and then I pull down the PWR KEY for 1s it is supposed to turn on . The status should show voltage.

But in my case I have tried manually pulling down the PWR KEY and nothing happens. Is there any mandatory config for other pins for this to happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure your power supply is rated for continuous 2 Ampere current or above. There's a lot of questions about powering these module, and mostly the problem is voltage(4.2v iirc) and often supplied cuurent available.

Comment: @jsotola sorry for the slip, this is is not chip , I meant to say it is not the eval board or module. The power is ok and I tested the power to run the module which runs perfectly

Comment: @Elementronics The power is ok and I tested the power to run the module which runs perfectly .